# What would a 3D graph of Riemann Zeta function look like?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Using a space filling Hilbert curve, we can map every point of a plane to a line in a smooth manner. Suppose we take output of Zeta(z) and map the resulting complex number using this technique to the axis perpendicular to the complex plane at (0, 0), and then plot the resulting surface. For ease of visualization, the 0 of y axis can map to (0, 0) of Zeta(z), i.e., the zeros of the zeta function. Is such a graph possible? What would it look like?

Comment: What about plotting $|\zeta(z)|$?

Comment: Hilbert's curve is *not* smooth.

Comment: This would totally depend on the space filling curve you chose, so in general nothing of interest would come ou

Comment: Yes but it will still be interesting to visualize for some arbitrary choice of curve.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The curve itself is not smooth but the mapping between the plane and the line is smooth (i.e., two nearby points on the plane are always nearby points on the line).

Comment: @Jus12 If you are trying to say that the Hilberts' map maps nearby points to nearby points, that's because it is continuous. It has nothing to do with smoothness.

Comment: @Jus12 You have to realise that with an arbitrary choice of curve, you'll also get arbitrary nonsense as the graph. Hillbert's curve is just one of infinitely many space filling curves, and has no special relation to the Riemann zeta function. So really you'll just get some random junk as a graph.

Comment: If you are interested in $\zeta(s)$ thus in the RH, you should plot instead Dirichlet series (and their inverse) for which the RH fails, it will be more interesting.